# Sharing Role environment storage among high availability instances

Tags: azure, asp.net-mvc-5, storage, multiple-instances, high-availability

I had a single instance MVC5 learning application whereby courses were stored on the C:\Resources\Directory\4af4cea9daae416992947a82ecce779e.Application.TempZipDirectory

I have now updated this to a high availability deployment with 2 instances and after getting the sessions shared amongst the two nodes I have ran into another problem as the courses found in the aforementioned storage location are not available when on the second node.

The courses are stored on each VM but I am wondering what would be the best approach for storing these files? They are zip files which I then store before extracting. I am not sure if blob storage is appropriate for this as most are folders with nested folders and I dont like how these are saved to flat storage.

Is there any means of sharing a resource such as the way I am currently doing it so that both instances could use the same storage for saving and playback?

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend you look into [Azure Files](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2014/05/12/introducing-microsoft-azure-file-service.aspx). It provides a SMB style share that could be accessed from both of your instances. Presuming you're using PaaS, you'll need to add a start-up script to the instance to mount the share. The powershell is available on the link above.

Comment: Cheers Brent will have a look now

Comment: Unfortunately it doesnt seem to be available for my subscription yet, I added the preview cache maybe this feature just isnt initialized for me

Comment: Its in preview, so you'll need to request access. http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/preview/

Comment: Brent do you have an example of how to do this programmatically? I have created the cloud share using C# code but I have been unable to figure out how to configure it as the share drive as I had when using role environment storage

Comment: Place the powershell at the link I provided into a start-up command for your PaaS role instance. Then your application will just access the files on that share as if they were a standard NTFS directory path.

Comment: Hi Brent, I tried this and it creates the folder as expected in both instances when done on startup.cmd but I cannot get access to the drive on the secondary instance I get username and password error